# При сборке в release пропадают данные привязанные через {Binding} MAUI. Что может мешать загрузить данные?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

В сборке Debug данные через привязку binding работают нормально. Но когда начинаю сборку в Release то на некоторых страницах не работают данные через привязки.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AutoShopMAUI.Views.CategoriesProductList"
             xmlns:viewmodel ="clr-namespace:AutoShopMAUI.ViewModels.Product"
             Title="Товары">
 
    <Grid>
        <CollectionView x:Name="categoryProductList" x:DataType="viewmodel:ProductViewModel"  ItemsSource="{Binding productsCollection}" IsVisible="{Binding IsReady}" >
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="15"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Frame Margin="3">
                        <VerticalStackLayout>
                            <Image Source="" HeightRequest="55" MinimumHeightRequest="55" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
                            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                <Label Text="Цена:"  />
                                <Label Text="{Binding SalePrices[0].Value}" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label Text="Р" />
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding indicatorIsRunning}" IsRunning="{Binding indicatorIsRunning}" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Так выглядит collection view в release:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так в Debug:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через logcat данные возвращаются и даже если присвоить в collectionviev itemsSource  observable collection то все равно текст пустой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если я не хочу по ссылке переходить? Ну вот религия не позволяет, то как тогда быть? Ну а если серьезно, вот протухнет ваша ссылка, вопрос в тыкву превратиться? Скорей всего да. Ну так зачем тогда это гемор со сторонними ресурсами?

Comment: Просто много кода, поэтому решил туда засунуть

Comment: Уместилось же, чего боялись - не пойму. Ну да ладно. Вы уверены, что дело в привязках, а не в данных, которые вы получаете? Ибо тут больше похоже на то, что у вас проблема с данными, самим привязкам без разницы, релиз это или дебаг.

Comment: Возможно ли как-то дебажить в Release? Или только через логи? Я тоже думаю, что может что-то с поступлением данных не так, но код не меняется же никак. Даже не могу предположить в чем проблема. Данные получаю со своего сервера через get запрос.

Comment: Самое простое - логи, выпишите данные в файл и проверьте их так, ну либо простое сообщение на экран выведите с одним объектом, например, будет там то, что надо? Если нет, то ищите по коду где есть такое место, на которое влияет релиз, также выводите в лог, смотрите.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138011/discussion-between-viknsagit-and-evgeniyz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось ошибка была в неправильном типе привязки данных. Поменял тип через:

```
<DataTemplate  x:DataType="viewmodel:Category">
```